# PHP Background Process Not Working

Tags: php, background-process, shell-exec

I'm using the following website to help me with background processes in PHP - http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/

My code is basically the same except my `shell_exec` method looks like this -
`nohup php -f /my/path/to/import_products.php 2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!`

The PHP script it's executing runs just fine and the products are imported, but when I add a `sleep(10)` to `import_products.php` the `while(is_process_running($ps))` only loops once and exits.

It seems like the command `shell_exec` is executing is completing immediately instead of waiting for 10 seconds (from the `sleep(10)`).

Any ideas why this might be?

**Edit**
I guess my question really is "Why isn't the process waiting for the PHP script to exit before it stops showing up in ps?" - Surely as the PHP script is sleeping for 10 seconds `ps $pid` should show that process for a minimum of 10 seconds?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Try checking the error logs for some more information.

Comment: `sleep` is dependent on `is_process_running` which is in a `while loop` most time except it is a `very long process` .. it would only run once then terminate

Comment: May I ask why you modified the code given in the link? What did it not do that you wanted it to?

Comment: **Bart S**: error reporting is enabled - nothing showing up. **Baba**: Could you explain that in a little more detail please? **DaveRandom**:  It hasn't really changed except I'm executing a PHP script instead of `hmmsearch ...`

Comment: You have altered the command that is being passed to `shell_exec()`... why? Also, are you trying to pass an argument of `2` to the PHP script, or is that supposed to be part of the output redirection?

Comment: Because I need to execute a PHP script instead of `hmmsearch`. And yes I'm passing `2` as an argument to the PHP script.

Comment: Where did the extra `> /dev/null` come from then? Did you add it is the string you passed to the function?

Comment: I added that as someone said in the comments on that site it was needed when running on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10536/discussion-between-sam-and-daverandom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code accordingly.

1. Add  `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/php` at the top of your php file before starting of php tag.
2. Change `shell_exec("nohup /usr/bin/php /my/path/to/import_products.php > /dev/null &")`.

Please note my php path is /usr/bin/php and I am using ubuntu os.So if your php executable path is different then replace this accordingly.

Comment: It looks like your `shell_exec` isn't returning the PID. If I add `echo $!` to the end of the command it works but I'm back to square one as it doesn't wait for the PHP script to finish.